# I want to take a user submitted string and search for that exact string in a log file and print the line number

Tags: python, full-text-search, pattern-matching

Currently, I am using a regular expression to search for a pattern of numbers in a log file. I also want to add another search capability, general user submitted ascii string search and print out the line number. This is what I have and trying work around (help is appreciated):

```
logfile = open("13.00.log", "r")

searchString = raw_input("Enter search string: ")
for line in logfile:
    search_string = searchString.findall(line)
    for word in search_string:
        print word #ideally would like to create and write to a text file
```

Comment: You got the "show what you have" part right, now you just need to ask a question :p

Comment: Re question title, you have my permission to do so.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your intelligence ... I'm enlightened!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, strings don't have a `findall` method -- I don't know where you got that. Second, why use a string method or regex at all? For a simple string search of the kind you're describing, `in` is sufficient, as in `if search_string in line:`. To get line numbers, a quick solution is the `enumerate` built-in function: `for line_number, line in enumerate(logfile):`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fairly fragmented. Psuedocode would look something like

```
get_search_string
for line, line_no in logfile:
    if search_string in line:
        do output with line_no
```